# JSON API Spec - Server Responsibilities Explanation

Tags: json, types, parameters, media, specifications

Can someone please explain to me what is expected by the following three points mentioned in the JSON API Spec?

> Servers MUST send all JSON API data in response documents with the header Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json without any media type parameters.

I've understood the first part where it mentions that the response of the needs have the `Content-Type` header set to `application/vnd.api+json`, but I cannot understand `without any media type parameters.` part.

> Servers MUST respond with a 415 Unsupported Media Type status code if a request specifies the header Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json with any media type parameters.

Again lost when it mentions `media type parameters`.

> Servers MUST respond with a 406 Not Acceptable status code if a request's Accept header contains the JSON API media type and all instances of that media type are modified with media type parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, a media type is pretty much the same as "Content-Type" it's just got a few extra mentions, for example:

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

1. They're saying don't ever respond with anything other than

   `Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json`
2. They're saying if the request `Content-Type:` header is not `application/vnd.api+json`, then respond with

   `Status: 415 Unsupported Media Type`
3. They're saying if the request `Accept:` header is not `application/vnd.api+json` then respond with

   `Status: 406 Not Acceptable`

**Note**:
They also mean no variants, example

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json+gzip
```

Is not acceptable

Comment: Thanks for your help :)